# Non-member function and abstract class

Tags: visual-c++

So the objective is to create an abstract 'shape' class with 'rectangle' and 'triangle' as derived classes. Finishing the assignment with printing the perimeters and areas of a rectangle and triangle using a non-member function in main(). I'm having trouble on how to use just one non-member function, as opposed to making a print function for each type of shape:

```
void printPerimeter(Triangle triangle);
void printPerimeter(Rectangle rectangle);
//I'm trying not to do this
```

```cpp
//what I had in mind, but don't know how to work this problem.
void printPerimeter(Shape shape)
{
    float temp;
    temp = shape.calcPerimeter();
    cout << "Perimeter: " << temp << endl;
}
```

I know an abstract class can't be passed into a function, so how could I go about this?

Comment: Your function will need to take a reference or pointer as a parameter in order to use polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Shape
{
private:

public:
    virtual void calcPerimeter()
    {
        cout << "Shape" << endl;
    }
};

class Triangle1 : public Shape
{
public:
    void calcPerimeter()
    {
        cout << "Triangle" << endl;
    }
};

class Rectangle1 : public Shape
{
public:
    void calcPerimeter()
    {
        cout << "Rectangle" << endl;
    }
};

void printPerimeter(Shape* shape)
{
    shape->calcPerimeter();
}

int main()
{
    Shape *triangle = new Triangle1();
    Shape *rectangle = new Rectangle1();

    printPerimeter(triangle);
    printPerimeter(rectangle);
    return 0;
}
```

Please, check if this helps you to achieve your goal. Courtesy:  @Retired Ninja